# Good way to organize group of constants in enum-like fashion

Tags: java

I'm trying to find a good way to orginize a group of constant values that are used simply for immutable data.

Here is what I'm currently attempting:

```
public class FishType {

    //PredatorFishType extends FishType
    public static final PredatorFishType SHARK = new PredatorFishType(5, 20, "Shark");
    public static final FishType CAT_FISH = new FishType("Cat Fish");

    private String name;

    private FishType(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

I use reflection to gather the final values into a collection aswell. I used to utilize enum but was forced to think of a new way to do this when different types of fish came into play such as the predator which contains other data such as food and so on. These constants are only used for data displaying purposes and have no reason to be mutated.

If there is some way to have multiple enum types within the same enum (If that makes any sense at all), that'd be great.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What do the integers in `PredatorFishType`s constructor do?

Comment: 5 is how many fish eat THEM, and 20 is how many fish they eat. NOT IRL accurate information, just made for an example.

Comment: Is there a specific problem with your approach?

Comment: Well the class loader does NOT like it and i get errors like "Referencing subclass PredatorFishType from superclass FishType initializer might lead to class loading deadlock"

Comment: How is PredatorFishType different from FishType? What extra methods does it have?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use constructor overloading or a combination of overloading and a wrapper class. If you know for certain that this data is immutable and will always be that way, I don't see anything wrong with sticking to enums for it. For the sake of putting it into one class, I've included the enums in the EnumTester class, but you may not want to do that.

Here's an example that prints "Cat Fish 5 20 Shark" and "Cow Fish" when run, using nothing but enums and a wrapper class. You could put accessors wherever you need them, depending on what you actually want to do with the information - I'm trying to demonstrate how to compose the two enums, not how to use them.

```
package enums;

public class EnumTester
{
    public enum MainType {
        CAT_FISH("Cat Fish"), DOG_FISH("Dog Fish"), COW_FISH("Cow Fish");   //everything has a name...
        private String name;

        private MainType(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getTypeDetails(){
            return name;
        }
    }

    public enum SubType {
        PREDATOR(5, 20, "Shark"), PREY(), MANATEE();    //but not everything has any additional information
        private boolean isFullSubType;
        private int val1;
        private int val2;
        private String subName;

        private SubType(int val1, int val2, String subName){
            this.isFullSubType = true;
            this.val1 = val1;
            this.val2 = val2;
            this.subName = subName;
        }

        private SubType(){
            this.isFullSubType = false;
            this.val1 = -1;
            this.val2 = -1;
            this.subName = "none";
        }

        public String getSubTypeDetails()
        {
            if( isFullSubType ) {
                return val1 + " " + val2 + " " + subName;
            }
            else {
                return "";
            }
        }
    }

    private MainType mainType;
    private SubType subType;
    public EnumTester(MainType mainType, SubType subType)
    {
        this.mainType = mainType;
        this.subType = subType;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EnumTester kittyShark = new EnumTester(MainType.CAT_FISH, SubType.PREDATOR);
        System.out.println(kittyShark.printDetails());

        EnumTester cowManatee = new EnumTester(MainType.COW_FISH, SubType.MANATEE);
        System.out.println(cowManatee.printDetails());
    }

    public String printDetails(){
        return mainType.getTypeDetails()+" "+subType.getSubTypeDetails();
    }
}
```

Comment: The only downside to this approach is duplicated code, and SubType not being a subclass to MainType.

Answer (score 0):

I typically follow a similar pattern to what you've done above. I might make the class `FishTypes` to be the collector, just to keep the `FishType` interface a bit cleaner. You can also invent some syntactic sugar to help you collect registered FishTypes:

```
public static final Set<FishType> registeredFish = new HashSet<>();
public static final PredatorFishType SHARK = register(new PredatorFishType(5, 20, "Shark"));
public static final FishType CAT_FISH = register(new FishType("Cat Fish"));

public static <T extends FishType> T register(T fishType) {
    registeredFish.add(fishType);
    return fishType;
}
```

Comment: This approach is bug-prone: anybody can call `registeredFish.clear()`. Mutable global state like this is a bad idea.